# How to custom caption in tex?

Tags: captions, titles

I want to bold the caption title without changing its description format like the figure below. I want all figures in this Tex files to have this kind captions, i.e., bold title + unbold description.

Currently, I can just make all fonts unbold.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=\linewidth]{dog.pdf}
\caption{title and long description} 
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far? Please also clarify what you're trying to achieve. Currently, only the first sentence of the caption text is in **bold**; do you want the entire caption text to be bolded? Do you want just on particular caption to be bolded, or should the text of all captions be bolded?

Comment: @Mico I have updated it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
\newcommand{\captitle}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

to your preamble and then use it like this

```
\caption{\captitle{A dog} followed by the rest of the text.}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be handy to define `\newcommand*{\mycaption}[2]{\caption[#1]{\captitle{#1} #2}}` to send only the short title to the LoF.